# Avoid re-entering credentials while using parse command line tool

Tags: parse-platform, command-line, parse-cloud-code

I have started using cloud code on parse.com, each time I try to deploy the new code using

```
parse deploy
```

I am being prompted to enter the email and password that I used to signup for parse.com, is there anyway to avoid this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this in Terminal in CloudCode folder

```
parse configure accountkey -d
```

For more information I suggest reading [this](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-account-keys-better-authentication-for-the-command-line-tool/) Parse blog post.